# Facing System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object issue

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception, error-messages

There is an issue with the test class:

> Error Message System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a
>   null object Stack Trace   Class.AnalyzeObjectBatch.start: line 30,
>   column 1

```
global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    system.debug('>>>>> Batch Start ');
    GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    string fieldStr = '';
    **Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName).getDescribe();**
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = objResult.fields.getMap();
    fieldSet = new Set<string>(objectFields.keyset());
    fieldAnalysisList = [select id,name,Populated_On__c,Type__c from Field_Analysis__c where Object_Analysis__c=:objForAnalysisID ];
    for(Field_Analysis__c fldA : fieldAnalysisList){
      if(fieldSet.contains(fldA.name)){
        fieldAnalysisOldMap.put(fldA.name,fldA);
      }else{
        fieldAnalysisListToDel.add(fldA);
      }
    }
```

Below is the test class I have written

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public class AnalyzeObjectBatchTests {

    static testMethod void testAuditTrailBatchDeleteTemp() 
    {
        Object_Analysis__c objAna = New Object_Analysis__c();
        objAna.Name = 'TestName';
        objAna.Record_Count__c = 1;
        objAna.Object_Name__c = 'Object Analysis';
        insert objAna;

        Field_Analysis__c fldAna = New Field_Analysis__c();
        fldAna.Name = 'Test';
        fldAna.Object_Analysis__c = objAna.Id;
        insert fldAna;


        Test.StartTest();    
        AnalyzeObjectBatch a = new AnalyzeObjectBatch(objAna.Id);
        Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(a);
        Test.StopTest();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following line is quite unstable in your code:

```
 Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName).getDescribe();
```

You are passing `objectname` argument. So, in any case if `objectname` is `null` or has value which is not a valid sobject API name then you will definitely get the error:

> Error Message System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a
>   null object Stack Trace

So, you must make sure that `objectname` is valid by adding condition like; `if(objectName != null)` and `if(GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName) != null)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ashwani answer,

```
global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
system.debug('>>>>> Batch Start ');
GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

string fieldStr = '';
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName).getDescribe();
```

The last line presumes `objectName` is a variable known to this class. Since this is a start method, it can only come from either

a) A value passed to the batch class's constructor

b) A static variable in the batch class

c) A value set on the class's instance before calling `Database.executeBatch(..)`

It looks like you are trying to do a) with

```
AnalyzeObjectBatch a = new AnalyzeObjectBatch(objAna.Id);
```

in your testmethod. But here you are passing an ID, not an objectname.